# Is there an equivalent to the None statement from Python in R?

Tags: python, r

For one of my classes we are having to try and do problems in Python and R but the questions sometimes give functions that are only useable in Python. One such question uses the None statement in Python but I cant seem to figure out an equivalent in R. I've looked into NA's and NULL but am not sure if these will work.

Comment: `None` is a literal value, not a statement.

Comment: ...and `NULL` is arguably its closest equivalent. Whether they "will work" depends on what you want to use them for -- you aren't telling us what the intended purpose is, so I don't know how we can say what "will work" for that unstated purpose.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways i can think of.
Here, num2 is an optimal parameter

1. Using the missing function within the function

```
ab <- function(num1,num2){
  if(missing(num2)) {
    num1
  } else {
    num1 + num2
  }
}

ab(1)
#1

ab(1,2)
#3
```

2. Set parameter as NULL

```
ab <- function(num1,num2=NULL){
  if(is.null(num2)) {
    num1
  } else {
    num1 + num2
  }
}

ab(1)
#1

ab(1,2)
#3
```

Yea, ideally you would want to add a check to ensure num2 is of a specific class type but this should be enough to get you started.